# NonlinearModelFit for nonlinear functions

Tags: fitting

I am trying to find a nonlinear model from the data.

[image]

My code is below:

```
data = {{0.0, 0.0}, {0.05, 0.87}, {0.1, 0.99}, {0.15, 0.98}, {0.2, 
   0.91}, {0.25, 0.81}, {0.3, 0.71}, {0.35, 0.62}, {0.4, 0.51}, {0.45,
    0.31}, {0.5, 0.31}, {0.55, 0.23}, {0.6, 0.18}, {0.65, 0.14}, {0.7,
    0.08}, {0.75, 0.05}, {0.8, 0.03}, {0.85, 0.02}, {0.9, 
   0.01}, {0.95, 0.002}, {1, 0}};

model=((1 - x)/(1 - a))^((0.5 (1 - a))/
          a) (x/a)^0.5;

(* fit model*)

    NonlinearModelFit[data, model, a, x]
```

**NonlinearModelFit** doesn't work for this model, i.e.

[image]

Are there any other ways to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Update:

If I try:

```
NonlinearModelFit[data, {model, {a > 0.000001}}, a, x]
```

Errors:

[image]

Comment: What about constrains for a - is it $0<a<1 $?

Comment: @AlexTrounev i try 
NonlinearModelFit[data, {model, {a > 0.000001}}, a, x] but it does not work...

Comment: Just curious:  Are the response variables relative frequencies and are the first and last responses (both 0) from observations?  Also should the 4th observation be `{0.15, 0.98}` rather than `{0.2, 0.98}`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use `NMimimize` to solve this problem as follows

```
data = {{0.0, 0.0}, {0.05, 0.87}, {0.1, 0.99}, {0.2, 
    0.98}, {0.2, 0.91}, {0.25, 0.81}, {0.3, 0.71}, {0.35, 0.62}, {0.4,
     0.51}, {0.45, 0.31}, {0.5, 0.31}, {0.55, 0.23}, {0.6, 
    0.18}, {0.65, 0.14}, {0.7, 0.08}, {0.75, 0.05}, {0.8, 
    0.03}, {0.85, 0.02}, {0.9, 0.01}, {0.95, 0.002}, {1, 0}};

f[a_, x_] := ((1 - x)/(1 - a))^((0.5 (1 - a))/a) (x/a)^0.5;


vec[a_] = Table[data[[i, 2]] - f[a, data[[i, 1]]], {i, Length[data]}];
sol = NMinimize[{vec[a] . vec[a], 0 < a < 1}, {a}]

(*Out[]= {0.0152585, {a -> 0.127671}}*)
```

Visualization

```
Show[Plot[f[a, x] /. sol[[2]], {x, 0, 1}], 
 ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Nice answer! can we still use fit function for this task?

Comment: We can use `NonlinearModelFit` with option `Method -> NMinimize` as it shown by xzczd.

Answer (score 11):

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, {model, 0 < a < 1}, a, x, Method -> NMinimize]
Plot[nlm[x], {x, 0, 1}]~Show~ListPlot@data
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice answer(+1). How you know about option  `Method -> NMinimize`? :)

Comment: @alex This is mentioned in **Details and Options** section of `NonlinearModelFit`: "Possible settings for Method include "ConjugateGradient", "Gradient", "LevenbergMarquardt", "Newton", "NMinimize", and "QuasiNewton", with the default being Automatic. " Also, an example setting `Method->NMinimize` can be found in **Options** section of document of **`FindFit`** (Yeah, no example in document of `NonlinearModelFit`, at least for now). But honestly speaking, I learned this when reading certain post in this site, IIRC. :)

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that NMinimize also takes options. For example Method->{NMinimize, Method->”RandomSearch”}

Comment: @DavidKeith thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 9):

The problem seems to stem from the first and last data points, with $x = 0$ and $x = 1$.  My guess is that it has to do with $\partial f/\partial x$ being singular at these points.  In addition, $\partial f/\partial a$ is singular when $a = 0$ or $a = 1$.

If you remove the offending data points, and give Mathematica an initial guess for $a$ that is away from the trouble spots, `NonlinearModelFit` runs without complaints & yields parameter `a -> 0.127671`.

```
newdata = Most[Rest[data]]
fit = NonlinearModelFit[newdata, model, {{a, 0.5}}, x]
Show[ListPlot[newdata, PlotStyle -> Orange], Plot[fit[x], {x, 0, 1}]]
```

[image]

Note that since the model automatically goes through the omitted data points for $0 < a < 1$, omitting them shouldn't affect the quality of the fit.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, that's why I suspected that first and last points aren't really data but "theoretical anchors" (for lack of a better term).  Also, the curve "shape" is that of a beta distribution and the x values are equally spaced which suggests some sort of binning of the observations (i.e., maybe fitting a probability distribution rather than a regression).